# Undo a git pull --rebase?

Tags: git

I just ran

```
git pull --rebase
```

and forget to specify "origin". It looks like git pulled from all different branches. Is there a way to revert my repo from here to undo the pull?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a `git pull` operation, `ORIG_HEAD` should point to the previous value of `HEAD`.  You should be able to:

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

And be back where you started before the `pull` operation.  You can run:

```
git show ORIG_HEAD
```

To see exactly where `ORIG_HEAD` is pointing prior to running the `reset` command.

An alternative solution would be to create a new branch based on `ORIG_HEAD`:

```
git checkout -b newbranch ORIG_HEAD
```

Verify that things look the way you expect, then delete the old branch and rename `new branch`.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git) for a discussion of `HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` and alternate syntaxes for referring to the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Use `git reflog`

You will see a whole bunch of commits HEAD that are from the past.

Safest is to checkout the HEAD you need in a new branch and continue from there

```
git checkout -b phew HEAD@{x} # fill in the number of the commit you need.
```

Comment: Thanks you saved me, I thought I lost it all.

Answer (score 3):

**Recovering from a borked/stupid/moribund rebase**

Accidently I ran `git pull origin master --rebase` instead of `git pull origin develop --rebase`.

I just wanted to revert what happened after rebase and get back to the last commit. I did not push to the remote branch.

It was a big mistake and want to get out of the merge.

The fastest way out of the merge is `git rebase --abort`