# git deleted my local project files, How can I restore these files

Tags: git, github, delete-file

I wrote these commands

```
git init -b main
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/sevoashraf499/OBARS.git
git push -u origin main
```

this gave me an error and I tried to solve it with these commands

```
git pull --rebase origin main
git pull origin main
```

but this deleted my local project
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question misses the output of these commands, especially the revisions that were overwritten. In such a case take a look into the `reflog`  and restore the revision you're looking for. This works unless those revisions are garbage collected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)

Comment: i wrote reflog and gave me this  bash: reflog: command not found

Comment: Yes, it requires learning first. Reading experience of technical documentation recommended, the git documentation is available at https://git-scm.com/doc - double check the version of git you're using. Learn how to make backups first, especially from git repositories as git is not a backup software just version control.

Comment: yes, I will learn it

Comment: but for now is there any way to recover these files?

Comment: When @hakre said "look into the `reflog`", he meant you to run `git reflog`.

Comment: Also, still paraphrasing hakre's comments, "the output of these commands" include the *error messages* of these commands. `git pull` can fail for quite a number of reasons (network issues ? access rights ? hooks ? conflicts ? ...), if we don't know which reason we can merely blind guess your issue.

Comment: Worth knowing : your basic go to command to check the state of your repository is : `git status`

Comment: Good idea, please add the output of `git status`  and `git reflog` to your question by [edit]ing it. And this perhaps gives better explanations as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10907173/367456

Comment: I tried the solution you've suggested and I followed the steps and added the output of git reflog and git status to the question

Comment: If you would now even be so eager and add the information not only as a screenshot but as text would be great. Let us know if you need more help editing the question.

Comment: and try: `git rebase --abort` (single command line) if it already solves your problem. @LeGEC was spot on with the `git status` suggestion.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status of your repo shows you are actually in the middle of the rebase on top of the pulled branch.

Try running `git rebase --continue` to proceed with your rebase.

If it doesn't work: given the current state of your [github repository](https://github.com/sevoashraf499/OBARS/) (at the moment: only [one single commit](https://github.com/sevoashraf499/OBARS/commit/ca50fdcb22ac861c3ecf3ad3ab2f4fbf73d07f56) with a basic `README` file which I assume was created through the web GUI of github), you can simply overwrite it :

```
git rebase --abort
git push --force-with-lease origin main
```

You may re-add a README file in your next commit.