# Using revert to state before last git pull --rebase state

Tags: git, rebase, git-pull, pull

I want to revert to the state before my last git pull --rebase request. I dont remember the last commit Id to which I can reset. This change I want to do locally , Any suggestions how to do it. I got the following using git reflog, dont know how to proceed.

```
 >git reflog 
 3b52052 HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
3b52052 HEAD@{1}: pull --rebase: checkout 3b520529dd08834067f316658bc450af1d6c5313
44e2c32 HEAD@{2}: clone: from https://xyy@bitbucket.org/abc-api/xyz.git
```

Comment: One option is find the `<SHA-1>` of the commit and then do `git reset --HARD HEAD~n`, where `n` is the number of steps to get back to the commit you want.

Comment: Pretty sure that first column is the commit ID, isn't it? So, you'd just want to reset to `44e2c32`, or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undoing a git pull --rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213235/undoing-a-git-pull-rebase)

Answer (score 4):

If the rebase only just happened, you can do:

`git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`

`ORIG_HEAD` stores the reference to the previous commit, prior to an operation such as a merge or rebase. Some more detail on `ORIG_HEAD` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/967611/149998).